# I cannot memory map large files. Map Failed. OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, file, nio, filechannel, file-mapping

Here is my code:

```
FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(afile.getAbsolutePath(), "r").getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
```

Here are the errors:

```
java.io.IOException: Map failed
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
```

I'm attempting to map a file of 1.5GB on a 32bit system.

I thought that nio was supposed to address this issue. Am I doing something wrong?

Regards.

Comment: What's max memory available to your jvm?